Issue in formating python string
I have a string like below in python
{
 "id": "123",
 "partition": "["partition_id=20240511"]"

}

output should be
{
 "id": "123",
 "partition": ["partition_id=20240511"]
}

I have tried with the optiona replace('"[','[') and replace(']"',']'), but no luck.
Can someone please share inputs here.
Thanks in advance.

Try using r"": https://realpython.com/python-raw-strings/ to avoid issues escaping square brackets?

you have this content in a file ? THen you want to load it as JSON ?

Can you specify the error message you are getting? The approach you mention should work to remove the extra double quotation marks. Are you trying to access the output as a dictionary afterwards? In this case you will have to convert it to an actual dictionary (rather than just a string) beforehand, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary.

I have it in a string and converting to json

Your solution seems to work just fine. What is the issue you are running into?

Error Message: "SyntaxError: invalid syntax, Perhaps you forgot a comma"

When I test your replace it works for me. Perhaps the syntax error is not in the replace args?

Use escape \ properly.
txt = "{" \
    "\"id\": \"123\"," \
    "\"partition\": \"[\"partition_id=20240511\"]\"" \
    "}"
    
    
print(txt)
    
x = txt.replace("\"[\"", "[\"")
x = x.replace("\"]\"", "\"]")
    
print(x)

